# Angularjs : use a function that returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I want to do some treatment once the function I called, which performs a call to the server, is done.

I tried :

```
vm.myFunction().$promise.then(function(){
    //some treatment done once vm.myFunction() is finished....
})


vm.myFunction = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        myResource.get(function(result){
            vm.results = result;
            for (var i=0; i<vm.results.length;i++){
                if (vm.results[i].state == 'open'){
                    deferred.resolve();
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        })
};
```

But I ma getting a

> angular.js:13294 TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of
>   undefined

How can I do that?

Comment: return myResource.get(func......

Comment: you are not returning anything from the function `return myResource.get()`, also there is no case where you will reject it - just to make sure you dont end up in infinite wait or add a timeout

Comment: You just return that `myResource.get(//code)` function. And no need to use `$promise` as you are already returning the promise.

Answer (score 3):

You must return deferred.promise at the end of the function.

```
vm.myFunction = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    myResource.get(function(result){
        vm.results = result;
        for (var i=0; i<vm.results.length;i++){
            if (vm.results[i].state == 'open'){
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
vm.myFunction().then(function(){
  //some treatment done once vm.myFunction() is finished....
})


vm.myFunction = function(){
var deferred = $q.defer();
    myResource.get(function(result){
        vm.results = result;
        for (var i=0; i<vm.results.length;i++){
            if (vm.results[i].state == 'open'){
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        }
    })
   return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all your answers, I managed to makeit work with :

```
vm.myFunction = function(){
        return myResource.get(function(result){
            vm.results = result;
            for (var i=0; i<vm.results.length;i++){
                if (vm.results[i].state == 'open'){
                    //....
                }
            }
        })
};
```